# Determine hosts for a play

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have multiple different apps running on different servers, e.g.

- `app-1` runs (in cluster mode) on `devserver-1` and `devserver-2`
- `app-2` runs (in cluster mode) on `devserver-3` and `devserver-4`
- `app-3` runs (in standalone mode) on `devserver-1`.

In my `dev`-intentory file I listed up all my 4 devservers.

Now I'd like to write a *parametrized* playbook which "knows" on which hosts it has to run when I provide an *app_name*-variable.

Currently I have a var file containing something like this:

```
# vars/apps.yml
apps:
  app-1:
    servers:
      dev:
      - devserver-1
      - devserver-2
```

And a playbook like this:

```
# playbook.yml
vars_files:
  - vars/apps.yml
hosts: "{{ apps[app_name].servers[stage] | join(',') }}"
```

But for various reasons I'm not happy with this configuration and want to avoid the usage of `vars_files` (and use roles/`include_vars` instead).

So how can I determine the hosts for a playbook (which is shared between multiple apps) without using `vars_files`?

Answer (score 1):

Group them in your hosts file, like this:

```
[app-1]
devserver-1
devserver-2
[app-2]
devserver-3
devserver-4
[app-3]
devserver-1
```

Then have your playbook use the variable in the `hosts` line:

```
- hosts: "{{ app_name }}"
```

(I honestly don't remember whether you can have a `-` in a group name.  Try it.)

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm not 100% happy with it because it will result in huge inventory files (as I have > 50 apps), but I will give it a try.

Comment: Well, you can populate each host's /etc/ansible/facts.d with some .fact files that tell the playbooks what goes where.